# Directory lookup failed when adding sample database to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am trying to add the AdventureWorks sample database to SQL Server 2012, but I get an error message:

> Msg 5133, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Directory lookup for the file "C:\Users\A\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Data\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf" failed with the operating system error 5(Access is denied.).

Answer (score 3):

The error message seems pretty straightforward: Access is denied. You need to make sure the SQL Server service account has adequate permissions on `C:\Users\A\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Data\`, or better yet, move the MDF (and LDF, if it exists) to the default data/log folders for the instance (where this shouldn't be a problem, and which is a better home for your database files anyway).

You can find the default data/log folders by inspecting:

```
SELECT physical_name FROM sys.master_files;
```

Any of the paths presented here should be a valid location to use...

Answer (score 1):

I would put the .mdf file in the default DATA directory, it will probably be something like:

```
 C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.INSTANCE_NAME\MSSQL\DATA
```

or

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11\MSSQL\DATA
```

The sever probably can't find the log file, this script rebuild the log (.ldf) file.

```
CREATE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012_Data
ON (FILENAME = N'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.INSTANCE_NAME\MSSQL\DATA\AdventureWorks2012_Data.mdf')
FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG 
Go
```

Answer (score -1):

While creating a new database provide database path outside users folder .
So , lot of permissions related issue are solved

[image]